# Kendo Grid DataSourceRequest Page Filter issue

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have kendo grid. When I filter in any page, DataSourceRequest shows the default page as 1. I want that if I filter in 2 page, I should see the request as Page 2 in MVC Controller Action Method.

Comment: Welcome to SO. So we can help you, can you add the code you have tried so far.

Comment: That could be tricky. http://www.telerik.com/forums/get-filtered-data-from-paged-grid